# AWS RDS MySQL retrieving data for certain table times out

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Strange problem with my database that I host using AWS RDS. For a certain table, I sometimes suddenly get timeouts for almost all queries. Interestingly, for the other tables, there are almost no time outs (after 150.000 ms which is the max I have set for the lambda, after that it terminates) while they contain similar data.

This is the Lambda (the function that gets the data from the database) log:

```
15:38:10 Connecting db: jdbc:mysql://database.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/database_name Connected
15:38:10 Connection retrieved for matches_table matches, proceeding to statement
15:38:10 Statement created, proceeding to executing SQL
15:40:35 END RequestId: 410f7edf-0f48-45df-b509-a9b822fa5c1c
15:40:35 REPORT RequestId: 410f7edf-0f48-45df-b509-a9b822fa5c1c Duration: 150083.43 ms  Billed Duration: 150000 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 115 MB
15:40:35 2019-06-04T15:40:35.514Z 410f7edf-0f48-45df-b509-a9b822fa5c1c Task timed out after 150.08 seconds
```

And this is Java code that I use:

```
LinkedList<Object> matches = new LinkedList<Object>();
try {
String sql = db_conn.getRetrieveAllMatchesSqlSpecificColumn(userid, websiteid, profileid, matches_table, "matchid");
Connection conn = db_conn.getConnection();
System.out.println("Connection retrieved for matches_table " +matches_table+", proceeding to statement");
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
System.out.println("Statement created, proceeding to executing SQL");
// execute the query, and get a java resultset
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
System.out.println("SQL executed, now iterating to resultset");
// iterate through the java resultset
st.close();

} catch (SQLException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(AncestryDnaSQliteJDBC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
return matches;
```

A couple of months ago I did a big database resources upgrade and some removal of unwanted data and that more or less fixed it. But if I look at the current stats, it looks ok. Plenty of RAM (1GB) available, no swap used, enough cpu credits.

So I am not sure if this is a MySQL problem or a database problem linked to RDW AWS. Any suggestions?

Comment: 150,000 ms is a nice round number, which probably means your query is just running too long. Try running it directly on the RDS instead of via your code.

Comment: 150.000 ms is the max amount of time I have set to the lambda. So after that, the lambda kills the process.

Comment: I suspect your query is taking longer than that timeout, then.

Comment: Actually, the query should take much less. Just a couple of seconds. The 150s is way too much. So I am pretty sure there is something else going on. Perhaps a limit on the number of entries in the MySQL database table?

Comment: There shouldn't be any row limits to RDS barring the limits of the underlying storage. Check your RDS console for any CPU, RAM, etc. limits being reached, and again, attempt the queries *directly* against the RDS to see if they take a long time there.

Comment: I just tested some of the failed queries. Interestingly, the first time I prepared one it took 20 sec. But the ones I did after varied from 3-10 sec, most of the time around 5 sec. And in addition, I am now doing some real heavy stuff on the db which now has 50% cpu usage (and burning up credits) while this process was not active when I was pulling the data and when it failed.

Comment: You likely don't want to be running your DB on a burstable instance. Run out of credits and performance will tank horribly.

Comment: Database is running on a db.t3.medium and never goes lower than 450 cpu credits, so not an issue.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: hi Wilson Hauck, I would love to but this server is a RDS DB server from AWS. So I can only report some general variables.

Comment: @helloworld Can you SSH login to the instance for MySQL Command prompt and SHOW DATABASES: ?  If Yes, try the SGS, SGV, SFPL.  If you have PHPADMIN available, the SQL tab will allow SGS, SGV, SFPL. If you can SSH login to the server and get a Command Line prompt, top, ulimit, iostat might produce output for you.  Will involve copying output to clipboard and paste into text file(s), save.  Post to pastebin.com or similar facility. Post links to into your question for visibility through SO.  One question has ~ 30,000 character limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it turned out to be an AWS specific thing. Turns out, there is some kind of IO credit system linked to the database. Interestingly, the chart that describes the number of credits left is not available in the default monitoring view of AWS RDS. You have to dive into CloudWatch and find it quite hidden. By increasing the allocated storage for this database, you earn more credits and by doing so I fixed the problem.